# Проверка БД PHP

Tags: php, запрос, база-данных

Хочу сделать проверку БД. Если запись есть, то вывожу надпись - OK. Если нету - ERROR.

Делаю запрос с софта вида: proverka.php?email_user=123@123.ru&num_user=1111.

База данных состоит из двух столбцов: email и num1, где email - varchar(60), а num1 - int(20).
Помогите реализовать алгоритм, пожалуйста.

Заметил ошибку.
Когда хочу вывести результат:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_row($row);
```

Пишет ошибку: Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ...

Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Вот часть кода
Код:

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'fx1';
$password = 'fx1';
$email_user = $_GET['email_user'];
$num_user = $_GET['num_user'];

$dblink = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);

if($dblink)
echo '';
else
die('');

$database = 'fx1';
$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dblink);
if($selected)
echo '';
else
die('');

$proverka = array(
email=> $email_user,
num1=> $num_user
);

$row = mysql_query("select 'num1' from 'fx1' where login='{$proverka[email]}' ");
$res = mysql_fetch_row($row);

?>
```

Comment: @nemtum, Вы наверное случайно ошиблись.Вы написали в вопросе:"База данных состоит из двух столбцов" - скорее всего таблица в конкретной базе данных состоит из 2 столбцов.Исправьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали что база(скорее всего вы имели ввиду таблицу) состоит из 2 столбцов: email и num1, а в запросе делаете выборку по полю login.
Скорее всего так:

```
$row = mysql_query("select 'num1' from 'fx1' where email='".$proverka[email]."' and num1='".$proverka[num1]."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

А Вы попробуйте видоизменить запрос:

```
$row = mysql_query("select 'num1' from 'fx1' where login='".$proverka[email]."' ");
```

как-то так :)

или так:

```
$row = mysql_query("select num1 from fx1 where login='".$proverka[email]."' ");
```

Comment: @gart67, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь. Снова ругается, но с другой ошибкой:

```
$row = mysql_query('select 'num1' from 'fx1' where 'email' = '.$proverka[email].'');
```

Пишет:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
```

Слегда переделал код:

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'fx1';
$password = 'fx1';
$email_user = $_GET['email_user'];
$num_user = $_GET['num_user'];

$dblink = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);

if($dblink)
echo '';
else
die('');

$database = 'fx1';
$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dblink);
if($selected)
echo '';
else
die('');

$proverka = array(
email=> $email_user,
num1=> $num_user
);

//$row = mysql_query("select 'num1' from 'fx1' where login='{$proverka[email]}' ");
$row = mysql_query('select 'num1' from 'fx1' where 'email' = '.$proverka[email].'');

$res = mysql_fetch_row($row);

if ($res == $proverka[num1]) {
     echo "OK";
} else {
     echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close($dblink);

?>
```